# Why spark row number returned less number of output

Tags: apache-spark

In my spark pipeline, it read last processed parquet files and new changes from MySQL. And then union them. The parquet files are distinct with primary key id. In then end the unioned data frame is applied a window row_number function: Window.partitionBy(id).orderBy(updated_at)
Uniondataset.withColumn(“rank”, functions.row_number().over(window)).filter(“rank=1”)

The output should be greater or equal to the original parquet files. I suspect the window function here gives me a record whose row number gets null values.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4Xzg.png)